# jQuery GET not succeeding

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, get

I'm trying to read from a list of threads as described in a file 'forum.xml'. I have come to realise that my GET request is not succeeding. Here is the XML file (which is not modifiable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE forum SYSTEM "forum.dtd">
<forum>
<thread>
    <title>Tea Party</title>
    <posts>teaParty.xml</posts>
</thread>
<thread>
    <title>COMP212 Exam</title>
    <posts>crypto.xml</posts>
</thread>
</forum>
```

and here is my js. I have tested that the element at target is being selected.

```
//threadReader.js
//Gets and display list of threads


var Threads = (function() {
var pub = {};
var target = $( ".thread");
var xmlSource = 'forum.xml';

function showThreads() {
    console.log("showThreads called");
    console.log(xmlSource);
    $({
        type: "GET",
        url: xmlSource,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            parseThreads(data, target);
        }
    });
}

function parseThreads(data, target) {
    console.log("parseThreads called");
    console.log(target);
    console.log(data);

    target.append("<ul>");
    $(data).find("title").each(function () {
        $(target).append("<li>");
        $(target).append($(this).text());
        $(target).append("</li>");
    });
}

pub.setup = function() {
    showThreads();
}

return pub;
}());

$(document).ready(Threads.setup);
```

any insight is always appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
function showThreads() {
    console.log("showThreads called");
    console.log(xmlSource);
    $({
```

to

```
function showThreads() {
    console.log("showThreads called");
    console.log(xmlSource);
    $.ajax({
```

Also be aware that your call to `$(".thread")` may not match any elements at the time you're calling it. Best to do that in your *document ready* handler.

Answer (score 0):

This may help in future. To get the correct Jquery Ajax syntax

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

In your case, I guess this should fire the call.

```
function showThreads() {
    console.log("showThreads called");
    console.log(xmlSource);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: xmlSource,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            parseThreads(data, target);
        }
    });
}
```